# Haskell pattern not matched [_]

Tags: string, list, haskell, pattern-matching

I have been trying to make the following code work:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-incomplete-patterns #-}
import Data.List
format :: String -> String
format [] = []
format (a:b:xs)
 | a == 'W' && b == 'U' = " " ++ format (drop 1 xs) 
 | otherwise = a : format (b:xs)

songDecoder :: String -> String
songDecoder xs = unwords. words . format $ xs
```

When I test with:

> songDecoder "AWUBBWUBC"

I expect "ABC" as output. However, I'm getting an unusual pattern matching warning:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘format’: Patterns not matched: [_]
```

I'm not sure why I need to match [_] when I have

```
format (a:b:xs)
```

Please help.

Comment: If you turn warnings on with `-Wall`, GHC warns about this at compile time, and points out the missing case to be matched. Recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Like [@EricFulmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488667/67579) writes in his answer, `(a:b:xs)` matches lists with *two or more items*. So your function works as:

```
format [] = ...       -- empty list
format (a:b:xs) = ... -- two or more
```

And Haskell is warning that a list with one element `[_]` will not match any of these lines: both patterns will fail.

You thus should add a clause, to specify what should happen in the case the list contains one element, for instance (and probably):

```
format a@[_] = a
```

Where `@` is an *alias operator* and it binds with a list with exactly one element.

In full we then obtain:

```
format :: String -> String
format [] = []
format a@[_] = a
format (a:b:xs)
 | a == 'W' && b == 'U' = " " ++ format (drop 1 xs) 
 | otherwise = a : format (b:xs)
```

We can make the function more elegantly, by by moving the comparisons into the pattern matching:

```
format :: String -> String
format [] = []
format a@[_] = a
format ('W':'U':xs) = format $ drop 1 xs 
format (a:b:xs) = a : format (b:xs)
```

Now the last case can be simplified into:

```
format (a:xs) = a : format xs
```

and now the second clause (our `format a@[_]`) becomes obsolete, since the last clause handles that case as well. So we turn the function into:

```
format :: String -> String
format [] = []
format ('W':'U':xs) = format $ drop 1 xs 
format (a:xs) = a : format xs
```

Personally I think this is is more elegant since here it is clear what you aim to match with the second pattern (you do not have to write a sequence of conditions). Furthermore one can almost syntactically see that the function handles all possible inputs.

Answer (score 4):

In the pattern `(a:b:xs)`, you're only matching lists of length >= 2. You're missing a pattern for a one-item list.

For example, these match `(a:b:xs)`:

1. `"AWUBBWUBC"` -- `a` is bound to `"A"`, `b` is bound to `"W"`, and `xs` is bound to `"UBBWUBC"` (syntactic sugar for `'U':'B':'B':'W':'U':'B':'C':[]`).
2. `"AWU"` -- `a` and `b` are bound as above, but `xs` is now bound to `"W"`.
3. `"AW"` -- `a` and `b` are again bound to `"A"` and `"W"` respectively.

Something like `"A"` wouldn't because you could bind `a` to `"A"` and `xs` to the empty list, but you don't have anything for `b`.

I hope this explains it!

Comment: Thanks Eric. I added format (a:[]) = a : [] and it worked!!

Comment: Glad to help. Added in more details on how patterns work. Hopefully they are useful to you in future Haskell coding!